# EKS internal service connection unreliable

Tags: kubernetes, service, amazon-eks, cni

I just setup a new EKS cluster (latest version available, using three default AMI).

I deployed a Redis instance in it as a Kubernetes service and exposed it. I can access the Redis database through internal DNS like : `mydatabase.redis` (it's deployed in the `redis` namespace). In another pod I can connect to my Redis database, however sometimes the connection takes more than 10 seconds.

It's doesn't seem to be a DNS resolution issue as host `mydatabase.redis` responds immediately with the service IP address. However when I try to connect to it, for example: `nc mydatabase.redis 6379 -v`  it sometimes connects instantly and sometimes takes more than 10 seconds.

All my services are impacted, I don't know why. I didn't change any settings in my cluster this a basic EKS cluster.

How can I debug this?

Comment: Please read this blog [Debugging network stalls on Kubernetes](https://github.blog/2019-11-21-debugging-network-stalls-on-kubernetes/)